# What is wrong with this $interval? Only fires on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
setTimeout(function(){
    userIsSetup = true;
    console.log('This happened!');
}, 4000);

$interval(function(){
    if(userIsSetup){
        $scope.received = true;
        $interval.cancel(); // Can pass a promise into this as well
    }
    console.log('A second has passed');
}, 1000, 30);
```

This is sort of a test for future functionality, but basically I just want to check to see if something is done once a second for thirty seconds. If it is done, stop the timer and turn on a variable so that something on the page disappears, otherwise after thirty seconds tell the user something was gonna take some time.

As the title says, the console log in the interval only happens once, when the page loads, and then doesn't happen again. Do I need to start the timer in some way or something?

Comment: Since you're using `$interval`, you could use `$timeout` too btw. Otherwise, can you check where you declared the variable `userIsSetup` and if you didn't forget to initialize it to `false` ?

Answer (score 1):

try with something like this.

```
 $scope.userIsSetup = false;
 $interval = setInterval(function(){
 $scope.check();
console.log('This happened!');
},2000);


$scope.check = function(){
        if($scope.userIsSetup){
            $scope.received = true;
            $interval.cancel(); 
        }
        console.log('2 second has passed');

   };
```

For the $interval in angular

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$interval) {


$scope.totalTimepassed = 0;


$scope.callAtInterval =  function () {

if($scope.totalTimepassed < 9)
{
$scope.totalTimepassed = $scope.totalTimepassed +1;
console.log($scope.totalTimepassed +" seconds passed");
}
else
{  
   $interval.cancel(interval);
   console.log("10 seconds passed");
}

}

var interval =  $interval($scope.callAtInterval, 1000);



});
```

Comment: This seems to work. Do you know why my original code did not?

Comment: since you are not assigning the setTimeout timer handle to $interval , you should assign it by $interval = setTimeOut(.

Comment: Actually, a problem I've just noticed with this code is that I'm now using setInterval as opposed to angular's $interval, meaning that things on the dom aren't updated with $interval (i.e the $scope.received variable won't update anything on the page).

Comment: yes , for angular $timeout  i have updated the code as well.

Comment: Hmm... the $interval code you posted doesn't seem to work for me. Something must be going on somewhere in my app but this is the only time in the entire app I've touched $interval.

If I use setInterval instead, is there a way I can update the dom like angular would so that the change for $scope.received is reflected on the view?

Comment: with set Interval you will have to call $scope.$apply() to ensure that any changes to the scope will be reflected.

Comment: This will have to do until I find a reason why $interval is being busted, thanks.